# Are there ways to write php/python code to run as hooks in the Apache Request Processing pipeline?

Tags: mod-perl

Does anybody know of any modules that provide the functionality to write python or PHP code to run as hooks in the Apache request processing pipeline?  For instance, mod_perl lets me write PerlModules, which can contain handlers for the header parsing phase, content delivery, and even filters.  I would like to do something similar in other scripting languages.

I could write it in C, but the goal is to deploy a module that would work across a number of systems.  If I deliver it as binary in C, then it would require 64/32-bit versions and some other issues.  With perl, I can just require certain modules installed and mod_perl2.

**EDIT** Ideally the module tech would be recent and not getting phased out like mod_python.  If no other solutions arise in a day or so, mod_python will be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

[mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) allows you to write hooks that can injected at a number of points within the request phase.

Comment: +1 for being true, but I will note that `mod_python` is being phased out in favor of `mod_wsgi`, which is a little more like CGI (but for Python).

Comment: does mod_wsgi also let you write hooks?

Comment: No. mod_wsgi is *only* for providing content.